# How do I create path-based routing rules for Azure Application Gateway in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-gateway

With Azure Portal I have manually created an Application Gateway using path-based routing. Now I need to automate this in C#. I can't seem to find any way to create a path-based routing rule. I'm using the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent package. What am I missing?

If this isn't supported through the Fluent API, is there a REST alternative?

Ex:

```
var appGw = Azure.ApplicationGateways.Define(AppGwName)
    .WithRegion(Region)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
    .DefineRequestRoutingRule("default") 
    // Now what?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find the [path-based routing settings](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/391e9bfe9424045226c8e3f06f05598bc9f400a6/src/ResourceManagement/Network/Generated/Models/ApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRuleType.cs#L27) in the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` package, but cannot find a way to configure it. And there is [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/173) related to this in github.

But it can definitely use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network/) package to create the `Application Gateway` with `path-based routing settings`.

Here is an example:

```
        ApplicationGateway gateway = new ApplicationGateway();

        //configure thepath-based routing.
        ApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule r = new ApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule();
        r.RuleType = ApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRuleType.PathBasedRouting;
        gateway.RequestRoutingRules.Add(r);

        //configure other settings.
        //gateway.Location = "xxx";

        gateway.Validate();

        //create the gateway.
        NetworkManagementClient networkManagementClient = new NetworkManagementClient(your_credential);
        networkManagementClient.ApplicationGateways.CreateOrUpdate("resource group name", "application gateway name", gateway);
```

The reference code example: [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/9f7f8b71079edb48f00a8c94e222039fe186e425/sdk/network/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network/tests/Tests/ApplicationGatewayTests.cs#L77) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/network/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network/tests/Tests/ApplicationGatewayTests.cs#L595).

For api, you can refer to [Create Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/applicationgateways/createorupdate#create-application-gateway). And in the request body, it defines the `path-based routing settings`.

Comment: Perfect. So many ways to configure things in Azure. Thanks again. This works for me.